# IE 9 and below not sending cookie to server for certain pages

Tags: http, cookies, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, session-cookies

I've set a cookie from the client (with path=/) using JavaScript (call it cookieA) and then the browser makes a bunch of AJAX requests. Most of these requests are sent along with a Cookie header as expected (containing my cookieA=value) but then I have a request (call it requestB) for which my cookie does not get sent to the server - requestB receives a second (different) cookie (call it cookieB) from the server using the Set-Cookie response header. Note that the requestB request references a file in a sub-directory.

Aside from requestB, all subsequent requests (for various files in various sub directories) contain my cookieA as normal again but they do not contain the cookieB which was set by requestB...

This issue only occurs in IE9 and below and not IE10 or any other browser.

What could cause this behavior?